# Mat and Vec_ types multiplication

Tags: opencv, mat

Is there any easy way to multiplicate Mat and Vec_? (Provided, that they have proper sizes, e.g.:

```
Mat_<double> M = Mat(3,3,CV_32F);
Vec3f V=(1,2,3);
result = M*V //?
```

Maybe there is some easy method of creating row (or col) Mat based on Vec3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't just multiply `Mat` and `Vec` (or, more generally, `Matx_`) elements. **Cast the `Vec` object to `Mat`**:

```
Mat_<float> M = Mat::eye(3,3,CV_32F);
Vec3f V=(1,2,3);
Mat result = M*Mat(V);
```

Also, I noticed an error in your code: when constructing `M`, the type `CV_32F` corresponds to `float` elements, not `double`. This is also corrected in my code example.

Hope that it helps.

Comment: Minor detail, but this isn't a "cast".  It is actually invoking the `Mat` constructor that accepts a single `Vec` as an argument.
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a507e01fb48b34a3e5c45f9f5b00725e8