# OpenCv, whats the Best way to multiply a 4x4 cv::Mat by a cv::Point3f?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

Currently I'm multiplying a 4x4 mat and a Point3f in a function this way,

Is there a more efficient way to do this multiplication?

Note: I also need to convert the result back to a cv::Point3f

Thanks

```
    cv::Mat cam_to_world(4, 4, CV_32FC1);
    ///....
    cv::Mat pointA_cam(4, 1, CV_32FC1);
    pointA_cam.at<float>(0, 0) = OAvec_cam.x;
    pointA_cam.at<float>(1, 0) = OAvec_cam.y;
    pointA_cam.at<float>(2, 0) = OAvec_cam.z;
    pointA_cam.at<float>(3, 0) = 1.0;
    cv::Point3f point_A_wld;
    cv::Mat point_A_world = cam_to_world*pointA_cam;
    point_A_wld.x = point_A_world.at<float>(0, 0);
    point_A_wld.y = point_A_world.at<float>(1, 0);
    point_A_wld.z = point_A_world.at<float>(2, 0);
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981214/opencv-how-do-i-multiply-point-and-matrix-cvmat) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863982/mat-and-vec-types-multiplication) might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have, if anyone has a more compact solution it would help

```
cv::Mat cam_to_world(4, 4, CV_32FC1);
cv::Mat pointA_cam = cam_to_world*Mat(cv::Vec4f(OAvec_cam.x,OAvec_cam.y,OAvec_cam.z,1.0));
cv::Point3f point_A_wld(cam_to_world.at<float>(0,0),cam_to_world.at<float>(1,0),cam_to_world.at<float>(2,0));
```

Comment: 3 lines is pretty compact, If you chuck that in a function you only ever need to right the complex bit once.